# What to call a linux mint converted to xfce?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions, window-manager, xfce

I'm using linux right now, I installed Linux Mint 7 (Gloria), but since then I switched to the xfce desktop, and I don't use any of the tools that come with mint (mintMenu, mintUpdate, mintInstall, etc). Instead, I use the normal xfce menu, Add/Remove (I suppose it comes with xfce), etc.

Also, I installed xubunutu-desktop (and then removed it) from synaptic.

I'm sure I'm not the first one to do something like that.

So, when I speak about the linux I use (such as posting a question about a problem I'm having) what should I call my operating system? linux mint? xubuntu? or what?

e.g.:

> I'm using xubuntu and I have a problem with XYZ

or

> I'm using linux mint and I have a problem with XYZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux Mint is built off of Ubuntu. If the problem is specific to the XFCE Desktop Environment (Things are displayed incorrectly), state that. If it is with internals (Network card isn't detected for example), specify Ubuntu as they are pretty much identical, and there is **far more support** available for Ubuntu so it will make things easier for you. You will also notice a lot of Mint users on Ubuntu forums for this reason.

You may want to see the main differences in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach is to always tag your questions (if tagging is an optiong) with **ubuntu** and **linux-mint/mint** and in the question just say:

> I'm running linux mint with Xfce as my GUI....

That should be well enough to get people where you are.